# @Query in Spring Repository not update rows and not get error

Tags: java, spring, entity, spring-repositories

I create custom method in Spring repository

```
@Transactional
@Modifying(clearAutomatically = true)
@Query("UPDATE Order co SET co.orderStatus =:status WHERE co.orderStatus =:newStatus")
int updateOrderStatus(@Param("status") OrderStatus status, @Param("newStatus") OrderStatus newStatus);
```

and call it in service:

```
log.info("started");
int i = orderRepository.updateOrderStatus(OrderStatus.CREATED, OrderStatus.PENDING);
log.info("updates: " + i);
```

And I see in logs:

> INF 15:43:45.102 started
>   INF 15:43:46.035 updates: 0

In DB I have 3 rows with `CREATED` status. I have not err and rows not update.

```
@Column(name = "order_status")
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
private OrderStatus orderStatus;

findAllByOrderStatus(OrderStatus.CREATED) get 3 rows
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your query is the other way around:

```
    @Transactional
    @Modifying(clearAutomatically = true)
    @Query("UPDATE Order co SET co.orderStatus =:newStatus WHERE co.orderStatus =:status")
    int updateOrderStatus(@Param("status") OrderStatus status, @Param("newStatus") OrderStatus newStatus);
```